# What do I have to do to unlock the "Train Heist" level?

Tags: payday-2

I was playing one of the new heists included in the Armoured Transport DLC - the underpass level specifically. After completing this heist I got an achievement - "But Wait - There's More!", and rather than getting to the experience screen we instead ended up on a new level called "Train Heist" in which we need to steal a turret weapon and its associated ammunition.

I have a few questions about this level;

- What do I have to do to unlock the "Train Heist" level?
- Does unlocking this level result in it becoming permanently available to choose or do you need to unlock it each time you want to play it?
- Is it a random chance to drop or will this always drop on certain difficulties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When opening up locked boxes inside armored cars in the new DLC heists, there is a chance that one of the boxes will contain intel. Picking up this intel item will unlock a subsequent "Train Heist" level after you complete your current heist. However, picking up the intel does *not* unlock the "Train Heist" level permanently.

The intel, when it drops, seems to be placed in the locked box closest to the back doors of the armored transport, so opening the trucks up with C4 will reduce your chances of finding intel.

Comment: I have opened a truck with C4 and still gotten the intel on the train. You just have a chance of destroying it in the blast.

Comment: Yeah, I just did a heist like that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well since the Spring Break update you can buy this contact from Bain in the contract broker section.